# WPF Custom combox item source

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom shape of a thermometer and I want to fill the background of it gradually depending on some input

Initially I thought of using some sort of Grid or Border but I can't seem to make the inside fill witohut the outside showing the color as well

this is the shape I want to use:

```
 <Path x:Name="path" Data="M17,17A5,5 0 0,1 12,22A5,5 0 0,1 7,17C7,15.36 7.79,13.91 9,13V5A3,3 0 0,1 12,2A3,3 0 0,1 15,5V13C16.21,13.91 17,15.36 17,17M11,8V14.17C9.83,14.58 9,15.69 9,17A3,3 0 0,0 12,20A3,3 0 0,0 15,17C15,15.69 14.17,14.58 13,14.17V8H11Z" Fill="Black" />
```

Is this possible without too much effort?

Comment: You could template a `Progress` control to make it look like a thermometer

Comment: You should have two geometries, one for the shape, one to fill.